# Dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged fired during page load resets item selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, code-behind, selectedindexchanged

I have an asp.net c# page that shows a list of organisations and also provides via text fields the 'type of organisation' and its address. I originally had the code working whereby selecting an organisation would fire the SelectedIndexChanged event and populate the extra textfields.

Now that I have added extra functionality to select this information from a record, the DropDownList always stays at the first option.

I would like the following to happen:

1. DropDownList to be filled with the list of organisations
2. The records oganisationID is used to select the appropriate item in the DropDownList
3. Populate the text fields accordingly
4. If the user select a different organisation from the list, the SelectedIndexChanged event populates the relevant fields again.

You will notice that I have hardcoded the ID 43 for the organisation. I was also having trouble passing that to the Organisation DDL. I may have been doing that part wrongly.
I have provided the asp.net and c# code-behind:

```
<%@ Page Title="Incident Record" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/common/master/incident.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="recordstackoverflowexample.aspx.cs" Inherits="incident_incidentdetails" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cp" runat="Server">

<!-- Forms
  ================================================== -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="well">
            <form class="bs-example form-horizontal" runat="server">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Incident Record</legend>

                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDSRecordPage" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString %>" DataSourceMode="DataSet" SelectCommand="uspRecordPage" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="RecordID" QueryStringField="recordid" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Organisation's contact details</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDSOrganisations" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [OrganisationID], [OrganisationName] FROM [tblOrganisation] WHERE ([IsCurrent] = @IsCurrent) ORDER BY [OrganisationName]">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="TRUE" Name="IsCurrent" Type="Boolean" />
                                </SelectParameters>
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
                            <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="DDLOrganisation" name="SelOrganisation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLOrganisation_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSOrganisationType" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [OrganisationID], [OrganisationName], [OrganisationType] FROM [tblOrganisation], [pickOrganisationType] WHERE [tblOrganisation].[OrganisationTypeID] = [pickOrganisationType].[OrganisationTypeID] AND ([IsCurrent] = @IsCurrent)  AND ([OrganisationID] = @OrganisationID)">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="TRUE" Name="IsCurrent" Type="Boolean" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLOrganisation" Name="OrganisationID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <label class="control-label">Organisation type:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtOrganisationType" class="form-control" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSOrganisationAddress" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [AddressLine3], [Town], [County], [Postcode], [Telephone], [Fax], [Email] FROM [tblOrganisationAddress] WHERE ([OrganisationAddressID] = @OrganisationAddressID)">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDLOrganisation" Name="OrganisationAddressID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <label class="control-label">Address line 1:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtOrganisationAddressLine1" class="form-control" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <label class="control-label">Address line 2: </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtOrganisationAddressLine2" class="form-control" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <label class="control-label">Address line 3:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TxtOrganisationAddressLine3" class="form-control" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-offset-2">
                            <a href="/incident/record.aspx">
                                <asp:Button class="form-control btn btn-success" ID="BtnUpdateRecord" PostBackUrl="~/incident/record.aspx" runat="server" Text="Update Record" /></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class incident_incidentdetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadOptions();
    }
}

protected void LoadOptions()
{
    DataTable organisations = new DataTable();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [OrganisationID], [OrganisationName], [OrganisationType] FROM [tblOrganisation], [pickOrganisationType] WHERE [tblOrganisation].[OrganisationTypeID] = [pickOrganisationType].[OrganisationTypeID] AND ([IsCurrent] = 1)", connection);

        adapter.Fill(organisations);

        DDLOrganisation.DataSource = organisations;
        DDLOrganisation.DataTextField = "OrganisationName";
        DDLOrganisation.DataValueField = "OrganisationID";
        DDLOrganisation.DataBind();

        //DDLOrganisation.SelectedIndex = DDLOrganisation.Items.IndexOf(DDLOrganisation.Items.FindByText("Name of Organisation"));
        DDLOrganisation.SelectedIndex = DDLOrganisation.Items.IndexOf(DDLOrganisation.Items.FindByValue("43"));

        DataView dv2 = (DataView)SqlDSOrganisationType.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataRowView drv2 = dv2[0];

        TxtOrganisationType.Text = drv2["OrganisationType"].ToString();


        DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDSOrganisationAddress.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataRowView drv = dv[0];


        TxtOrganisationAddressLine1.Text = drv["AddressLine1"].ToString();
        TxtOrganisationAddressLine2.Text = drv["AddressLine2"].ToString();
        TxtOrganisationAddressLine3.Text = drv["AddressLine3"].ToString();


    }
}


protected void DDLOrganisation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv2 = (DataView)SqlDSOrganisationType.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView drv2 = dv2[0];

    TxtOrganisationType.Text = drv2["OrganisationType"].ToString();


    DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDSOrganisationAddress.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView drv = dv[0];


    TxtOrganisationAddressLine1.Text = drv["AddressLine1"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationAddressLine2.Text = drv["AddressLine2"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationAddressLine3.Text = drv["AddressLine3"].ToString();


}





protected void SQLDSRecordPage_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@RecordID"].Value = Request.QueryString["recordid"];
}



/*
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
string selectedID = DDLOrganisation1.SelectedItem.Value;

SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand     ("SELECT [AddressLine1], [AddressLine2], [AddressLine3], [Town], [County], [Postcode], [Telephone], [Fax], [Email] FROM [tblOrganisationAddress] WHERE ([OrganisationAddressID] = @OrganisationAddressID)", connection);
theCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrganisationAddressID", selectedID);
theCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

using (SqlDataReader theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (theReader.HasRows)
    {
        // Get the first row
        theReader.Read();

        // Set the text box values
        //CustomerName.Text = theReader.GetString(0);
        TxtOrganisationAddressLine1.Text = theReader["AddressLine1"].ToString();
    }
} 




    DataView dv2 = (DataView)SqlDSOrganisationType.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView drv2 = dv2[0];

    TxtOrganisationType.Text = drv2["OrganisationType"].ToString();


    DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDSOrganisationAddress.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView drv = dv[0];


 //   TxtOrganisationAddressLine1.Text = drv["AddressLine1"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationAddressLine2.Text = drv["AddressLine2"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationAddressLine3.Text = drv["AddressLine3"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationTown.Text = drv["Town"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationCounty.Text = drv["County"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationPostcode.Text = drv["Postcode"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationTelephone.Text = drv["Telephone"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationFax.Text = drv["Fax"].ToString();
    TxtOrganisationEmail.Text = drv["Email"].ToString();
}


}
    */
}
```

Thanks

Sam